# Android Room tutorial does not build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-room

**UPDATE: Solved! (see fix at the bottom)**

I'm trying to go through the Android Room tutorial but get stuck on step3. I keep getting an error when trying to update the gradle file as specified by the tutorial.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1

[image]

When trying to build, I get the following error:
[image]

[image]

Setting roomVersion to "2.1.0-alpha06" or just "2.1.0" generates the same type of error.

Is it only me or is there something wrong with this tutorial?

Anyone with an idea why the **`androidx.room:room-testing`** dependancy fails to build?

[image]

**UPDATE**:
I solved the issue by uninstalling Android Studio and re-installing it. I also needed to do a full cleanup and remove all "android studio" and "gradle" related files on my system. Maybe a bit overkill, but this is whats fixed it for me.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same in a different project? Works fine for me

Comment: is this due to some network error?

Comment: @NovoLucas Yes, As its only step 3 I have tried creating a new project and starting over, but with the same result. I can't find any way to fix this error, other than commenting out the room-testing dependency. If it works fine with you makes me belive there is hope at some level :)

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu Its no a network issue, as I can test-update the other libraries with other version-numbers just fine.

Comment: Weird, i just added `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0'` in one of projects. synced fine!

Comment: Try to invalidate caches and restart in the original project.

Comment: I tried on my laptop with a fresh install of Android Studio, and it works there as well. Seems like there is something fuzzy going on with my Android Studio installation. It is somehow configured wrongly :-) Uninstalling / reinstalling now to see if it helps as I have no other suggestions on how to fix this.